# How to find the exception error point of the Image Button in this log?

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-room, imagebutton

I've been struggling with this 'android.view.InflateException' issue in this log for a long time. The issue was that an activity composed of the Room database and Recyclerview could not be executed in API level 21/22. Of course, if I adjust the minSdk 21 setting higher to 23, that's it. But I didn't want to do that.

I initially thought this was an issue with LinearLayoutManager or something because of the 'Caused by: android.view.InflateException' message in the log.

Eventually I found out that the issue was caused by the ImageButton. However, I didn't find out by looking at this logs, I found it in debugging myself. Looking at these numerous log lines, is there any way to decipher that it is an Image Button related issue? (Of course, there are log line about Image Button.)

The cause of the issue was that Api level 21/22 higher finds the location of the image in the drawable folder, but Api level 21/22 devices cannot find the location of the images for button.

Shouldn't Android Studio itself prevent this feature from being used on low-spec devices?

I would like to hear from the experts on how to effectively read the log. Thank you in advance.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2434)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2494)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900 (ActivityThread.java:157)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1356)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5527)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:730)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:620)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:539)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:423)
at com.w_myApp.databinding.ActivityRoomBinding.inflate (ActivityRoomBinding.java)
at com.w_myApp.databinding.ActivityRoomBinding.inflate (ActivityRoomBinding.java)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity$rbaBinding$2.invoke (RoomActivity.java)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity$rbaBinding$2.invoke (RoomActivity.java)
at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue (SynchronizedLazyImpl.java)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity.getRbaBinding (RoomActivity.java)
at com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest$Builder.build (AdRequest.java)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity.getMAdView (RoomActivity.java)
or                     .onCreate (RoomActivity.java)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity.goScrollPosition (RoomActivity.java)
or                     .onCreate (RoomActivity.java)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity.onCreate (RoomActivity.java)
or                     .setMAdView (RoomActivity.java)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity.getRoot (RoomActivity.java)
or                     .onCreate (RoomActivity.java)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity.joinBlocking (RoomActivity.java)
or                     .onCreate (RoomActivity.java)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking (BuildersKt__Builders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking (Builders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default (BuildersKt__Builders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default (Builders.kt)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity.goScrollPosition (RoomActivity.java)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity.onCreate (RoomActivity.java)
or                     .runBlocking (RoomActivity.java)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking (Builders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default (BuildersKt__Builders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default (Builders.kt)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity.goScrollPosition (RoomActivity.java)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity.newCoroutineContext (RoomActivity.java)
or                     .onCreate (RoomActivity.java)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking (BuildersKt__Builders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking (Builders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default (BuildersKt__Builders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default (Builders.kt)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity.goScrollPosition (RoomActivity.java)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity.getDefault (RoomActivity.java)
or                     .onCreate (RoomActivity.java)
at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineContextKt.newCoroutineContext (CoroutineContext.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking (BuildersKt__Builders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking (Builders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default (BuildersKt__Builders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default (Builders.kt)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity.goScrollPosition (RoomActivity.java)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity.getIO (RoomActivity.java)
or                     .onCreate (RoomActivity.java)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity.decrementUseCount$default (RoomActivity.java)
or                     .onCreate (RoomActivity.java)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking (BlockingCoroutine.java)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking (BuildersKt__Builders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking (Builders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default (BuildersKt__Builders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default (Builders.kt)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity.goScrollPosition (RoomActivity.java)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity.incrementUseCount$default (RoomActivity.java)
or                     .onCreate (RoomActivity.java)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking (BlockingCoroutine.java)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking (BuildersKt__Builders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking (Builders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default (BuildersKt__Builders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default (Builders.kt)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity.goScrollPosition (RoomActivity.java)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity.cancelCoroutine (RoomActivity.java)
or                     .onCreate (RoomActivity.java)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking (BlockingCoroutine.java)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking (BuildersKt__Builders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking (Builders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default (BuildersKt__Builders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default (Builders.kt)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity.goScrollPosition (RoomActivity.java)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity.isCompleted (RoomActivity.java)
or                     .onCreate (RoomActivity.java)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking (BlockingCoroutine.java)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking (BuildersKt__Builders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking (Builders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default (BuildersKt__Builders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default (Builders.kt)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity.goScrollPosition (RoomActivity.java)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity.onCreate (RoomActivity.java)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:6272)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1108)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2387)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2494)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900 (ActivityThread.java:157)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1356)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5527)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:730)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:620)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:782)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:704)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:835)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:798)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:838)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:798)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:515)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:423)
at com.w_myApp.databinding.ActivityRoomBinding.inflate (ActivityRoomBinding.java)
at com.w_myApp.databinding.ActivityRoomBinding.inflate (ActivityRoomBinding.java)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity$rbaBinding$2.invoke (RoomActivity.java)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity$rbaBinding$2.invoke (RoomActivity.java)
at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue (SynchronizedLazyImpl.java)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity.getRbaBinding (RoomActivity.java)
at com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest$Builder.build (AdRequest.java)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity.getMAdView (RoomActivity.java)
or                     .onCreate (RoomActivity.java)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity.goScrollPosition (RoomActivity.java)
or                     .onCreate (RoomActivity.java)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity.onCreate (RoomActivity.java)
or                     .setMAdView (RoomActivity.java)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity.getRoot (RoomActivity.java)
or                     .onCreate (RoomActivity.java)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity.joinBlocking (RoomActivity.java)
or                     .onCreate (RoomActivity.java)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking (BuildersKt__Builders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking (Builders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default (BuildersKt__Builders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default (Builders.kt)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity.goScrollPosition (RoomActivity.java)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity.onCreate (RoomActivity.java)
or                     .runBlocking (RoomActivity.java)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking (Builders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default (BuildersKt__Builders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default (Builders.kt)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity.goScrollPosition (RoomActivity.java)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity.newCoroutineContext (RoomActivity.java)
or                     .onCreate (RoomActivity.java)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking (BuildersKt__Builders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking (Builders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default (BuildersKt__Builders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default (Builders.kt)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity.goScrollPosition (RoomActivity.java)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity.getDefault (RoomActivity.java)
or                     .onCreate (RoomActivity.java)
at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineContextKt.newCoroutineContext (CoroutineContext.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking (BuildersKt__Builders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking (Builders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default (BuildersKt__Builders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default (Builders.kt)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity.goScrollPosition (RoomActivity.java)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity.getIO (RoomActivity.java)
or                     .onCreate (RoomActivity.java)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity.decrementUseCount$default (RoomActivity.java)
or                     .onCreate (RoomActivity.java)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking (BlockingCoroutine.java)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking (BuildersKt__Builders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking (Builders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default (BuildersKt__Builders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default (Builders.kt)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity.goScrollPosition (RoomActivity.java)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity.incrementUseCount$default (RoomActivity.java)
or                     .onCreate (RoomActivity.java)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking (BlockingCoroutine.java)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking (BuildersKt__Builders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking (Builders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default (BuildersKt__Builders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default (Builders.kt)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity.goScrollPosition (RoomActivity.java)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity.cancelCoroutine (RoomActivity.java)
or                     .onCreate (RoomActivity.java)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking (BlockingCoroutine.java)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking (BuildersKt__Builders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking (Builders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default (BuildersKt__Builders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default (Builders.kt)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity.goScrollPosition (RoomActivity.java)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity.isCompleted (RoomActivity.java)
or                     .onCreate (RoomActivity.java)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking (BlockingCoroutine.java)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking (BuildersKt__Builders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking (Builders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default (BuildersKt__Builders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default (Builders.kt)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity.goScrollPosition (RoomActivity.java)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity.onCreate (RoomActivity.java)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:6272)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1108)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2387)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2494)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900 (ActivityThread.java:157)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1356)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5527)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:730)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:620)
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: 
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie (Resources.java:2705)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable (Resources.java:2643)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable (TypedArray.java:870)
at android.widget.ImageView.<init> (ImageView.java:152)
at android.widget.ImageButton.<init> (ImageButton.java:84)
at android.widget.ImageButton.<init> (ImageButton.java:80)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton.<init> (AppCompatImageButton.java)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton.<init> (AppCompatImageButton.java)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageButton (AppCompatViewInflater.java)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView (AppCompatViewInflater.java)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:746)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:704)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:835)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:798)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:838)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:798)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:515)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:423)
at com.w_myApp.databinding.ActivityRoomBinding.inflate (ActivityRoomBinding.java)
at com.w_myApp.databinding.ActivityRoomBinding.inflate (ActivityRoomBinding.java)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity$rbaBinding$2.invoke (RoomActivity.java)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity$rbaBinding$2.invoke (RoomActivity.java)
at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue (SynchronizedLazyImpl.java)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity.getRbaBinding (RoomActivity.java)
at com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest$Builder.build (AdRequest.java)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity.getMAdView (RoomActivity.java)
or                     .onCreate (RoomActivity.java)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity.goScrollPosition (RoomActivity.java)
or                     .onCreate (RoomActivity.java)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity.onCreate (RoomActivity.java)
or                     .setMAdView (RoomActivity.java)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity.getRoot (RoomActivity.java)
or                     .onCreate (RoomActivity.java)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity.joinBlocking (RoomActivity.java)
or                     .onCreate (RoomActivity.java)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking (BuildersKt__Builders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking (Builders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default (BuildersKt__Builders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default (Builders.kt)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity.goScrollPosition (RoomActivity.java)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity.onCreate (RoomActivity.java)
or                     .runBlocking (RoomActivity.java)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking (Builders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default (BuildersKt__Builders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default (Builders.kt)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity.goScrollPosition (RoomActivity.java)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity.newCoroutineContext (RoomActivity.java)
or                     .onCreate (RoomActivity.java)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking (BuildersKt__Builders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking (Builders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default (BuildersKt__Builders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default (Builders.kt)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity.goScrollPosition (RoomActivity.java)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity.getDefault (RoomActivity.java)
or                     .onCreate (RoomActivity.java)
at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineContextKt.newCoroutineContext (CoroutineContext.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking (BuildersKt__Builders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking (Builders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default (BuildersKt__Builders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default (Builders.kt)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity.goScrollPosition (RoomActivity.java)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity.getIO (RoomActivity.java)
or                     .onCreate (RoomActivity.java)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity.decrementUseCount$default (RoomActivity.java)
or                     .onCreate (RoomActivity.java)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking (BlockingCoroutine.java)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking (BuildersKt__Builders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking (Builders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default (BuildersKt__Builders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default (Builders.kt)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity.goScrollPosition (RoomActivity.java)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity.incrementUseCount$default (RoomActivity.java)
or                     .onCreate (RoomActivity.java)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking (BlockingCoroutine.java)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking (BuildersKt__Builders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking (Builders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default (BuildersKt__Builders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default (Builders.kt)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity.goScrollPosition (RoomActivity.java)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity.cancelCoroutine (RoomActivity.java)
or                     .onCreate (RoomActivity.java)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking (BlockingCoroutine.java)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking (BuildersKt__Builders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking (Builders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default (BuildersKt__Builders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default (Builders.kt)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity.goScrollPosition (RoomActivity.java)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity.isCompleted (RoomActivity.java)
or                     .onCreate (RoomActivity.java)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking (BlockingCoroutine.java)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking (BuildersKt__Builders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking (Builders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default (BuildersKt__Builders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default (Builders.kt)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity.goScrollPosition (RoomActivity.java)
at com.w_myApp.RoomActivity.onCreate (RoomActivity.java)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:6272)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1108)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2387)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2494)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900 (ActivityThread.java:157)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1356)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5527)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:730)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:620)
```

I inform those  who are struggling in similar issue logs like me. There are numerous suggestions in this log, but there was only one reason for the exception to occur. Image Button. Low level devices can't find the image location.

Comment: Have you read https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/stacktraces

Comment: Android Studio, itself, will not prevent features from being used on low-spec devices.

Comment: @MikeT Sorry for the late reply. Thank you for your comments.